# Error while trying use project's classes into another project

Tags: c#, reference

i have this structure:

1. Entity:(It's a Project named "Entity" - type: ClassLib)

   - Class 1;
   - Class 2;
   - Class 3;
2. DataBase:(It's a Project named "DataBase" - Type: ClassLib)

   - Class 1;
   - Class 2;
   - Class 3;
3. MainProject: (Windows Form)

   - Some Forms;

Then what I did was:

- Added both projects into MainProject's *references*
- Wrote on the *codebehind*:

  - *using DataBase;*

Worked perfect... But when I try to add the *DataBase Project* into the *codebehind*, it doesn't show up while I'm typing and also give me this error:

*Error  2   The type or namespace name 'DataBase' could not be found (are you missing   a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Ps: All the Classes of the projects (Class 1,2,3...) have the same namespaces wich is the project's name.

I tried some stuff I found on the internet, but nothing worked... Any Idea why?

**UPDATE**

My Code:

**MainProject**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Entity; ( WORKED ! I can acess Entity's Class)
using DataBase; <----------------------------------    (ERROR HERE)
```

Comment: It's 100% unclear what `BD Project` is from the question.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It's a Class Library...

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: but which class library? None of the projects mentioned are `BD Project`.

Comment: @mason I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question. But I added the *using* together with the others *using* like *Using System.Data*.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I don't get it... I added a Class Library, then I added some normal classes inside this. BD is the name of my LibClass.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, please add your code. Add the `using` statement to the question as well as the code that's not compiling.

Comment: Does your DataBase project have the Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3 classes in the "DataBase" `namespace`?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Now that I checked this out, again... One of the classes wasn't with the same namespace, I changed it and it's working now o.O 
But I have no idea why it doesn't showed the others classes, they are all PUBLIC... ?

Comment: What do you mean by "show the classes"?

Comment: @mason I have 3 classes, they are all *public* but only ONE wasn't with the appropriate *namespace*, ok ? So Why I couldn't add the DataBase's reference on the *codebehind*  by typing *using DataBase;" ?

Comment: You did not answer my question. I asked what you mean by "show the classes". You can easily type `using Database;` at the top of your code behind. And as long as you have a reference to the assembly that the classes are in, it WILL compile.

Comment: @mason I confused myself, just forget the "show class". I Just don't understand why the error vanished only after I change that class namespace, knowing that the other classes were with the right namespace. I know, "it's working now... yay". But I wanted to understand the cause of the error...

Comment: For testing purposes only, please undo your "wrong-placed" class namespace change to its original and try to reference this class on your codebehind directly on code (without including it). For example, `Database.Whatever.ClassMisplaced`.

Comment: @HuorSwords Error... Once I renamed the class namespace then I pressed [Ctrl] + [.]. And it replaced everywhere, I guess that's what caused the problem...